# Visual Studio's debugger doesn't display more than 99 elements of a C++ container

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, debugging

I am trying to inspect all elements of a std::set container in my C++ app, but visual studio 2005/2010 only displays the first 99 elements.  How do I configure the IDE to show all elements?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you get this ability out-of-the-box with VS2008 but it seems to have gone away in VS2010. I just tried this in both VS2008 and VS2010:

```
std::set< int > s;

for(int i = 0; i < 400; ++i)
{
    s.insert(i);
}
```

Setting a breakpoint afterwards and then using the Locals or Watch panels, if I expand s the debugger shows me all 400 elements below it in VS2008 but only the first 100 in VS2010.

I don't remember configuring anything in VS2008 to make this happen.

FWIW, with C-style arrays and general pointers, you can tell the debugger how many elements to show. p,200 would show the 200 elements from *p onwards. That doesn't seem to work with std::set objects, though. :(

Answer (score 0):

I see exactly the same thing at home on VC++ Express 2010.  My guess is that to get around this you would have to use one of the paid-for versions of the IDE.  How irritating.

Comment: I do have the payware versions of VS2005/2010.  Still I can't find a config option in Tools -> Options or Tools -> Customize..